# Conic section and perpendicularity

Tags: linear-algebra, conic-sections

I have a problem which, once again, is probably quite simple, but I can't get my head around how I'm supposed to show the required equivalence. The following problem is from a book called 'Linear Algebra', and the problem is within a sub-chapter where rotating the coordinate axes has just been introduced so using analysis (or anything not relating to linear algebra) is not preferred. Here's the problem:

Suppose that $x_0$ is a point on the genuine conic section $\alpha$: $x^\top Ax + b^\top x + c = 0$. (Here $A = A^\top \in \Bbb{R}^{2 \times 2}$, $b \in \Bbb{R}^2$ and $c \in \Bbb{R}$.) Show that the line $x = x_0 + tu$ (where $t \in \Bbb{R}$) is tangent to $\alpha$ if and only if $u$ is perpendicular to the vector $2Ax_0 + b$.

I first assumed that $u$ is perpendicular to the vector $2Ax_0 + b$. This means that their inner product is zero. Then, by substituting the line's equation to the conic section's equation gives

\begin{align*}
&(x_0 + tu)^\top A(x_0 + tu) + b^\top(x_0 + tu) + c = 0 \\
\iff \, &x_0^\top Ax_0 + b^\top x_0 + c + tu^\top(2Ax_0 + b) + t^2u^\top Au = t^2 u^\top Au = 0.
\end{align*}

These were used above:

- $x^\top_0 Au = u^\top Ax_0$,
- $u^\top(2Ax_0+b)$ was assumed to be equal to $0$,
- $x_0^\top Ax_0 + b^\top x_0 + c = 0$ because it was assumed that $x_0 \in \alpha$.

But there, at the end, I'm not sure if I can just assume that $u^\top Au \neq 0$. Because If I can, then $t^2$ must be equal to $0$, which implies that the line $x = x_0+tu$ is a tangent to the conic section because then $x_0$ (being any point on $\alpha$) is the only point of the line that touches $\alpha$.

To show the other direction I have no idea how I could achieve this. Nothing seems to work with the tools I have available. Can you give me a hint or two about how to proceed?

Edit 0: Grammar and typos.

Edit 1: Here, $x_0$ is a fixed vector of $\Bbb{R}^2$.

Edit 2: Genuine conic section means that the curve is either a real ellipse, a hyperbola, or a parabola (not a degenerate version of any of them).

Comment: The gradient of the quadratic polynomial is perpendicular to the tangent by definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But there, at the end, I'm not sure if I can just assume that $u^\top Au
> \neq 0$. Because If I can, then $t^2$ must be equal to $0$, which
> implies that the line $x = x^0+tu$ is a tangent to the conic section
> because then $x^0$ (being any point on $\alpha$) is the only point of
> the line that touches $\alpha$.

We need to be careful here - it is certainly possible for a line to intersect a conic section at only one point and yet not be tangent (consider the $y$-axis for $y=x^2$.)

On that note, we need to clarify what it means for a line to be tangent to a conic section.  If you wish to avoid analysis, I would propose we say that $x^0+tu$ is tangent to $\alpha$ if $x^0$ is on $\alpha$ and the line *does not cross* $\alpha$, which we might formalize by demanding one (and only one) of the following inequalities is simultaneously satisfied for all $t \neq 0$ and $z=x^0+tu$:
$$z^\top A z + b^\top z + c >0\text{,}$$
$$z^\top A z + b^\top z + c <0\text{.}$$

Now, using calculations similar to the ones in your question, we obtain

\begin{align*}
&(x_0 + tu)^\top A(x_0 + tu) + b^\top(x_0 + tu) + c \\
= \, &x_0^\top Ax_0 + b^\top x_0 + c + tu^\top(2Ax_0 + b) + t^2u^\top Au \\
= \, & tu^\top(2Ax_0 + b) + t^2 u^\top Au \text{.}
\end{align*}

The last expression is a quadratic in the variable $t$ (unless $u^\top Au=0$, which we will deal with separately), and so the vertex is at $t=-u^\top(2Ax_0 + b)/(2 u^\top Au)$.  The line is tangent to $\alpha$ if and only if the quadratic equals $0$ only at $t=0$ *and* does not change sign, or equivalently, the vertex is at $t=0$, which in turn occurs if and only if $u^\top(2Ax_0 + b)=0$.

Finally, we deal with the case where $u^\top Au=0$, in which case the aforementioned "quadratic" is not a quadratic at all, but simply a non-constant* linear function $ tu^\top(2Ax_0 + b)$, which passes through $0$ at $t=0$ alone, and thus $u^\top (2Ax_0+b)$ is nonzero.  Since the function is linear and non-constant, it must take on positive and negative values, and thus the line is not tangent per our definition.

(*Note that we know it is non-constant since otherwise, it would be constantly equal to $0$, and then the entire line would pass through the conic section, contradicting nondegeneracy.)

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't even come to think that I can just look at the equation as a quadratic equation of t. Since the theory introduced rotation of the coordinate axes, I had been trying to use 90 degree rotation in order to reach some sort of solution but wasn't able to.

Comment: I found another way of proving that u⊤Au=/=0.  
Suppose that u⊤Au=0. Then u and Au must be perpendicular to each other which in turn implies that A must be a matrix that rotates vector u 90 degrees. So A must be a 2x2 matrix as follows:

A =  [ [ cos(a)    -sin(a) ] [ sin(a)     cos(a)] ] ,

where the angle a is π/2 or -π/2. But in this case x⊤Ax = 0 and α wouldn't be a conic section. Therefore, u⊤Au =/= 0.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn’t work, as you are neglecting the possibility that $u$ is in the null space of $A$, which is very possible in our setting.  $A$ could e.g. be the matrix $(e_1,0)$ where $e_1=(1,0)^T$, which is not a rotation but still satisfies $e_2^T A e_2 = 0$, where $e_2=(0,1)^T$.

Comment: The bottom line is you won’t find a proof that $u^TAu\neq 0$ because that’s simply not guaranteed to be true.  Notice in my proof I never showed that it couldn’t vanish, I merely established that if it did vanish, then the line was not tangent and at the same time the vectors $u$ and $2Ax_0+b$ we’re not perpendicular.

Comment: Also, knowing $x^T A x=0$ for *some* nonzero $x$ does *not* preclude $\alpha$ from being a conic section.  The parabola $y=x^2$ is an example, which indeed uses the same matrix $A$ as in my previous comment.

Comment: Actually, looking back at your original proof, I realize you may have meant “I can prove $u^T A u\neq 0$ in the case that I already know u is perp to $2Ax_0+b$“.  If that’s what you meant, then yes, that is in fact true, though you can’t use the rotation argument for the reasons I outlined.

Comment: And what I actually meant in my "second proof attempt", was that if the rotation argument would have worked and that the matrix A had been like I wrote earlier (that is, orthogonal with a 90 degree angle), then α would not have been a conic section. Because then x⊤Ax = 0 for all x. But since A is not necessarily orthogonal, then this is not true, as you have showed.